# VB.NET: Possible to separate function into sections?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to divide a function into sections, something like this?

```
Function myFunc

  Section
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    ...
  End Section

  Section
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    ...
  End Section

End Function
```

I realize it could be done with

```
If True Then
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  ...
End If
```

but that seems like a hack

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend refactoring your "Sections" into separate functions or subs, and calling them as appropriate.  The fact that you want this separate seems like it highlights an opportunity for refactoring....

Comment: Is that what you would consider the best practice in every situation like this?

Comment: @ic3b3rg: I don't what Reed says, but I would say "absolutely"! If you want to know why, read the book "Clean Code" from Robert Martin (http://jesseliberty.com/reviews/book-review-clean-code-by-uncle-bob-martin/)

Comment: @ic3b3rg: Most likely, yes.  In general, if you can separate your function into smaller functions, you should do so.  This makes them easier to maintain, and more testable.  It also helps the functions follow the SRP more closely  (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Should I change my function to a class?  Then I could encapsulate it and all sub-functions into the one class?

Comment: @ic3b3rg: If your function makes sense as a class, then yes.  If this function is dependent on the other data in the class, and "logically" an operation of the class where it exists, I'd leave it alone and just split it up.  (The fact that you're asking suggests "yes", but it's tough to know what's best without a lot more information...)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to separate your function into... more functions.

If you do too much in one function, it can be hard to maintain. Your functions and methods should really be there to do one task or one specific function. Anything more than that and you should split it into multiple functions.

Try and thing of a literal name for the function, e.g. `CreateDatabaseConnection`. If you have a name like `CreateDatabaseConnectionAndSelectContacts` (i.e. with an 'And' in the name), it might be a candidate for refactoring.